# Is there a definition for describing nuclear material undergoing fission/fusion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

Is there a term similiar as a piece of coal burning as ambers?

Can nuclear material undergoing the reaction be transported?

Comment: On your first question, I have no idea what you're asking. On your second question, there are such things as nuclear-powered submarines and aircraft carriers.

Comment: your spelling is wrong: amber is a mineral, you mean  "Coal embers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a definition for describing nuclear material undergoing fission/fusion?
>
> Is there a term similiar as a piece of coal burning as embers?

No, mainly because of the complexity and size of the systems.

> Can nuclear material undergoing the reaction be transported?

For fusion to happen you need a [Tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak) or something like that , unless you mean a hydrogen bomb while exploding.

For fission a reactor or a bomb. ["critical"](https://mitnse.com/2011/03/18/what-is-criticality/) is a term used when fission starts. No way like transportable embers.

Comment: I meant an example like Uranium undergoing a fusion reaction at a nuclear reactor

Comment: It will be in a solid mass of uranium and moderators,  dimension of meters. There are rods of fuel and rods of moderators,  when the reactor is critical they can be manipulated .Nothing that can be picked up the way embers can be picked up with a shovel. Huge and complex machinery is needed, or robotic arms.

Comment: Uranium undergoes fission (splitting apart), not fusion (joining together).

Comment: @Nederealm  as G.Smith notes, it is fission and not fusion in uranium. Fusion is with light nuclei in hot plasma.

Comment: You do have nuclear subs, though.

Comment: @stafusa if you call them shovels :)

Comment: @annav Now that would be a novel definition of nuclear-powered submarines: shovels for fission embers. :-D